# Differentiate XMLs based on namespace in Apache Camel

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, apache-camel, xslt-1.0

I am using Spring Boot and Apache Camel in my project. The architecture is some XML is coming from an input queue to Camel layer where it is transformed to another XML using XSLT and them the final XML is sent to an output queue.The XML which is coming is of the following form

```
<tns:Standalone xmlns:tns="namespace1">
    <tns:name>Test</tns:name>
</tns:Standalone>
```

and this is correctly getting transformed using an XSLT. The problem is in my flow, the tns of the incoming XML can vary (say a different XML can come with tns as namespace2). Then the XSLT is failing. So I need to have logic to use differentiate the incoming XMLs based on tns valueso that I can use different  XSLTs for both the scanarios. Can you please guide me how can I differentiate input XMLs based on tns?

Comment: If you want, you can write a single XSLT that will handle nodes in different namespaces differently.

Comment: Can you please give me the idea of how to do so?

Comment: Not unless you expand on what you want to do in each case.

Comment: I want to transform the message to a target message and want to do the same transformation in both the cases. In both the cases only the tns of the incoming message will differ and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing how you can use a single XSLT to handle equally nodes in two different namespaces:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="namespace1"
xmlns:ns2="namespace2"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 ns2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns1:Standalone | /ns2:Standalone">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns1:name | ns2:name"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this stylesheet is applied to either one of the following inputs:

**XML 1**

```
<tns:Standalone xmlns:tns="namespace1">
    <tns:name>Test</tns:name>
</tns:Standalone>
```

**XML 2**

```
<tns:Standalone xmlns:tns="namespace2">
    <tns:name>Test</tns:name>
</tns:Standalone>
```

the result will be:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>Test</output>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. I was not aware of OR condition while checking in XSLT.

Comment: Actually, `|` is the union operator, not an OR.